# Why PostgreSQL store data in hex in own format?

Tags: postgresql

I can't understand the reason why PostgreSQL store [data](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) in own format

> The "hex" format encodes binary data as 2 hexadecimal digits per byte, most significant nibble first. The entire string is preceded by the sequence \x (to distinguish it from the escape format).

Does it's mean that it is not simple `hex` and it would not possible to simple convert this `hex` to `byte` type and I should write parser of PostgreSQL hex format?

Comment: That is **not** the format the data is _stored_ in. It is the format the data is encoded in a literal or when send back to the client.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  So on client I would not get classical hex and would need to write special hex converter?

Comment: That format is used by the library that talks to the server, e.g. the JDBC driver or libpq. You only need to worry about that if you want to write a constant value as in the examples

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So it's impossible to get binarray as is without this intermediate format? Any attempt to read data in field as byte [] will return not this hex string?

Comment: That depends on the driver you are using. The JDBC driver supports binary transport and I would assume libpg as well. If you use `getBytes()` on a result set you'll get the raw binary data. Why do you care how it's transmitted?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am just to trying understand how its work. But you mostly answer to my question) thanks)

Answer (score 1):

The client driver usually takes care of `bytea` conversion for you, supplying you a native language data type like `byte[]` for Java. The representation of `bytea` on the wire shouldn't generally concern you. The only time it'll really matter is if you're using bytea literals in SQL text, rather than sending them as bind parameters.

Anyway, it *is* normal hex, it just has a `\x` prefix. So it's utterly trivial to "parse" if you do need to do so manually. E.g. in Python

```
r'\x736f6d65737472696e67'[2:].decode("hex")
```

---

The reason for the `\x` prefix is largely historical. PostgreSQL used to use an octal escape format for `bytea` data. When the format was changed to hex - to make it easier for clients to consume and work with and make it a bit more compact - it was necessary for the client to be able to tell what format the data was in. Since `\x` can never appear in octal ("escape") format literals, any string beginning with `\x` must be a hex bytea literal. This is even more important when receiving data from a client, which might be sending either `hex` or `escape` style literals, and the server must be able to tell which is which.

We could've just required that all clients use the format specified by the server. But that would break compatibility for all old clients that use `bytea`. Personally I think that's exactly what we should've done, and required that people using old clients set `bytea_format = escape` or something. That's not what happened, though. The setting `bytea_output` controls the format the server sends, but it still understands both formats as input. That makes interoperating with old clients and scripts easier. In theory.

In practice lots of old clients  blindly interpreted hex literals sent by the server as if they were escape-format even though they were invalid; they'd ignore the backslash or treat it as a literal backslash. So they'd tend to corrupt bytea data when loading it then saving it again. Exactly what we wanted to avoid.